# ggplot unknown extra factor level in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot and I am not sure why there is an extra factor level showing up in my plots.

here is the structure of my dataframe:

```
> str(Int_mltL)
'data.frame':   123144 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ File.name : Factor w/ 5864 levels "6-1_LB-1_P2-H-2_01_4587.mzXML",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ variable  : Factor w/ 21 levels "peak1","peak2",..: 6 1 7 2 8 3 9 4 10 5 ...
 $ value     : num  597 203 255 0 130 ...
 $ valueL    : num  6.39 5.32 5.55 0 4.88 ...
 $ PA14_locus: Factor w/ 4434 levels "EMPTY","PA14_00020",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ SmpType   : Factor w/ 32 levels "6","PA14_EM_1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ OD500     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ IntStd    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ PlNm96    : Factor w/ 61 levels "ExMr_nr_mas_01_1",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Col96     : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Row96     : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Cntrl     : chr  "LB" "LB" "LB" "LB" ...
 $ Locus     : Factor w/ 294 levels "","EMPTY","PA14_00680",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ GeneName  : Factor w/ 12 levels "","pchC","pchD",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ BMtype    : Factor w/ 4 levels "","pch","phz",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Sum.valL  : num  86.1 86.1 86.1 86.1 86.1 ...
 $ Med.valL  : num  86.1 86.1 86.1 86.1 86.1 ...
```

The factor that I want to group by (BMType) seems to have 4 levels.  But 5 boxplots show up.  What is this 5th level and how can I remove it.

[image]

Thank you

```
> unique(Int_mltL$BMtype)
[1] <NA> rhl  phz  pch      
Levels:  pch phz rhl
```

Comment: Yes, four levels ("",  "pch", "phz", "rhl") + `NA` values results in 5 groups.

Comment: A code example how you set up the ggplot-object would be helpful. You could use `na.omit(Int_mltL$BMtype)` to remove missings.

Comment: thanks, feel silly, I was just confused becaused it shows NA when it lists factors, and only says 4, but I guess NA is not considered as a factor, and "", empty is the 4th factor, and NA is the 5th category but isn't considered a factor

Comment: Do you want an empty string to be considered a factor?  if not, you can set these values to missing when you read the data in . Have a look at the `na.strings` argument of `read.table` et al.